# TomEE upgrade from 8.0.13 to 9.0.0 spring application : Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, apache-tomee

We got a security incident to update TomEE from 8.0.13 to 9.0.0. After updating we couldn't able to start our application, we are using spring based application but our build process it something, we are building war file and this war file will be deployed to TomEE server(9.0.0).

Please find my pom.xml below, can anyone help me in resolving this?

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.6


com.company
myapplication
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
myapplication
war

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.apache.poi
poi
5.2.3


org.apache.poi
poi-ooxml
5.2.3


com.opencsv
opencsv
5.7.1


jakarta.xml.bind
jakarta.xml.bind-api


com.sun.xml.bind
jaxb-impl
2.3.8
runtime


com.google.guava
guava
31.1-jre


net.sf.flexjson
flexjson
3.3


org.apache.commons
commons-lang3



javax.ws.rs
javax.ws.rs-api
2.1.1


org.apache.httpcomponents
httpclient
4.5.14



org.apache.httpcomponents
httpmime
4.5.14

```
    <!--new Changes for client change -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20220924</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sa</groupId>
        <artifactId>edx_api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- START Flexlm license dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexlm</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
        <artifactId>EccpressoAll</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexlmmgmt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexlmutil</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END Flexlm license dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- New changes event bus -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>5.17.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>MyApplication</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

````
>  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
>                 at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:512)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:420)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:414)
>                 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:413)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
>                 at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:512)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:420)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:414)
>                 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
>                 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:413)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
>                 at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:222)
>                 at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:83)
>                 at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2371)
>                 at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2019)```


Expectation is it should run without any errors.




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myApplication</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--new Changes for client change -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <!--new Changes for client upload file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <!--new Changes for client upload file -->

        <!--new Changes for client change -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sa</groupId>
            <artifactId>edx_api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START Flexlm license dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexlm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoAll</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexlmmgmt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.macrovision</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexlmutil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Flexlm license dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- New changes event bus -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.17.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MyApplication</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
````

Comment: (1) TomEE 9 apply Jakarta EE 9 (2) Jakarta 9, Servlet 5.0, JSP 3.0 (3) Servlet is `jakarta.servlet.Servlet` NOT `javax.servlet.Servlet` (4) I guess TomEE 9 does not provide built-in javax.servlet.Servlet lib.

Comment: thank for the info @life888888, let me try adding javax.servlet externally

Answer (score 2):

TomEE 9 supports the Jakarta namespace (EE 9.1) only and won't work with the Javax Namespace.

You need to stick with EE8 (= TomEe 8.0.x) or migrate your app and its dependencies to the Jakarta namespace. Adding javax dependencies to TomEE 9 won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Tomee 9 is based on Tomcat 10 and packages like *javax.servlet* have been renamed to *jakarta.servlet* breaking your application (and third party libraries) dependency to javax.servlet package.

To ease the migration,Tomcat provides a tool to convert your application and its dependencies for you.

From Tomcat 10 migration guide:

https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html

> Tomcat can convert an existing web application from Java EE 8 to
> Jakarta EE 9 at deployment time using the Apache Tomcat migration tool
> for Jakarta EE. To make use of the feature, the web application should
> be placed in the Host legacyAppBase folder (by default named
> webapps-javaee) and they will be converted to an equivalent Jakarta EE
> web application in the Host appBase folder (by default named webapps).
>
> Alternately, the Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE or any
> similar conversion tool can be used ahead of time to benefit from
> faster deployment time and more precise conversion configuration
> options.

In my case I'm running the tool using the Ant task from my pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Yes it is a very old version -->
    <version>1.8</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/jakartaee-migration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakartaee-migration</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>javax2jakarta</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <taskdef name="javax2jakarta"
                        classname="org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.MigrationTask"
                        classpath="jakartaee-migration-*-shaded.jar" />
                    <javax2jakarta
                        src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war"
                        dest="${project.build.directory}/tomee9/${project.build.finalName}.war"
                        profile="tomcat" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you don't need two wars files (one compatible with Tomee 8 and and the other with Tomee 9) you can run the plugin in a phase before *package* directly on the build folder : `src=${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}`

**Note**: In my case it solved NoClassDefFoundError / ClassNotFoundException issue for javax.servlet.* classes but at the moment I'm still facing issues regarding Spring 5 usage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this dependency

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api/2.3.3

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to run `mvn clean install` or whatever you like to pull your dependencies for your project